# MySQL query with distinct and order by showing error 3065(HY000)

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct

I am using linux mint in my machine and trying to execute a query. After the execution, an error is displayed

> ERROR 3065 (HY000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'shelterl_local.animal.changed' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

I added line

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=''
```

in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and restarted mysql. But still getting the same error. I referred many solutions but nothing worked for me. My query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT fs.etid AS etid FROM og_membership fs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN node animal ON animal.nid = fs.etid LEFT OUTER JOIN 
field_data_field_for_animal dfa ON dfa.field_for_animal_value = fs.etid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN node pastid ON pastid.nid = dfa.entity_id WHERE ( (fs.gid = 
464) OR 
(animal.nid IN   
(1196113,1211208,1218831,1243640,1254254,
1253603,1249890,1261729,1261282,1258378,1273745,1270760,
1279219,1276040,1276031,1275684,1288727,1289306,1300545,
1313770,1313761,1313755,1313746,1313330,1312388,1310673,
1309431,1315024,1333640,1328041,1323565,1327216,1330104,
1327786,1326810,1335812,1333094,1341309,1340358,1348088,
1351077,1351071,318214,1342698,1472755,1491527,1351652,1353488,
1507763,1342713)) )AND (fs.entity_type = 'node') 
AND (animal.type = 'animal') AND (animal.status = 1) AND (pastid.title LIKE 
'%A%') 
ORDER BY animal.changed DESC LIMIT 0,300;
```

Is it possible to remove this error permanently and execute the query? Please help

Comment: MySQL does not know _which_ value of `field2` to use when sorting.  You need to tell us how you want to sort.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have added the actual query. Please take a look

Comment: The full query is actually largely irrelevant to your question.  You can comment on my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial query is equivalent to the following:

```
SELECT field1 AS f1
FROM table t
--Joins and conditions
GROUP BY field1
ORDER BY field2 DESC LIMIT 0,300
```

This can't make logical sense, because each value of `field1` in the result set may have *multiple* values of `field2` associated with it.  The error you are seeing is MySQL's way of saying it can't figure out what you want to do.  One workaround would be to sort on an aggregate of `field2`, e.g. try the following:

```
SELECT field1 AS f1
FROM table t
--Joins and conditions
GROUP BY field1
ORDER BY MAX(field2) DESC   -- or AVG(field2), or MIN(field2), etc.
LIMIT 0,300
```

Comment: In Case 1: Mysql will consider whichever first come in record but it will not generate an error.

Comment: @Jack No, I don't believe that statement is completely accurate.  I think you are correct if MySQL is running with strict mode turned off, otherwise I would expect the error from the OP.  Actually, if you check the documentation you will see that often `SELECT DISTINCT` is done using `GROUP BY` under the hood.

Comment: Yes strict mode should be turned off if such an error occurred. @Arun Here order by animal.changed is not making that much sense in output. Can I know based on what are you wishing sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually select field2

```
    SELECT DISTINCT field1 AS f1,
    field2
    FROM table t
    --Joins and conditions
    ORDER BY field2 DESC LIMIT 0,300
```

UPDATE:

I know sometimes theres errors when using DISTINCT and ORDER BY in the same query. To fix this i would give the animal.changed section an ALIAS such as [animal.changed] and then if you ORDER BY [animal.changed] this should not error. At least i know this definitely works in SQL server

E.G

```
    SELECT DISTINCT animal.changed AS [animal.changed]
    FROM .....
    ORDER BY [animal.changed]
```

This is very basic but would allow you to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY in the same query which is the current error you're getting.

Comment: I need to work the query in the edited question to work. Please take a look

Comment: This would fix the error, but it is a different query.

Answer (score 0):

If you select a column then sorting can only be done for this column. If you need to sort by another column, then necessarily include this column in the selection.

*//wrong.....*

```
$sql="Select DISTINCT Rubrika from tmp3 order by View desc limit 3";
$res_r=mysqli_query($Link, $sql);
```

//RIGHT!!!

```
$sql="Select DISTINCT Rubrika, View from tmp3 order by View desc limit 3";
$res_r=mysqli_query($Link, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue and abled to resolve it. Since I'm using Windows I'll post fix for windows but similar fix will work for linux as well.

This is happening because **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** mode is enabled by mysql. You can disable this by modifying **my.ini** file. (In linux this would be my.cnf).

1. Open my.ini file.
   This file might be located in a hidden directory **ProgramData**.

   ```
    C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0
   ```
2. Find following config which is placed under [mysqld] section.

   ```
   sql-mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
   ```
3. Remove **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** from here

   ```
   sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
   ```
4. Restart mysql server

   ```
   net stop MYSQL80
   net start MYSQL80
   ```